# URL rewriting is rewriting ALL my files with two segments

Tags: c#, regex, web-config

This is my rule in web config

```
<rule name="rewrite">
  <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/review.aspx?c={R:1}&amp;t={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Which successfully turns `review.aspx?c=value&t=value` into `/value/value`

My problem now is, my `/css/style.css` now loads as `review.aspx`

Is there a way to stop this? Not only with CSS, but with all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rewrite rule conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rewrite-rule-configuration) makes it possible for you to limit the application of the rewrite rule, such that it only applies to those requests where the conditions have been met.

By defining a condition like the one below, you can ensure that rewriting only occurs for URLs that doesn't match an existing file.

```
<rule name="rewrite">
  <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/review.aspx?c={R:1}&amp;t={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

The way that it works is that for each request, before the rewrite occurs, the rewrite engine checks if the defined condition has been met and then skips the rewrite rule in case the condition wasn't met.

The condition we define is: The request must not refer to an actual file on disk.

The reason for this is that we only want the rewrite to applied to requests with virtual URLs like `/value/value` and not requests for static files like `/css/style.css`.

To break down exactly what the different attributes of the condition means:

- `input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"` tells the rewrite engine that we want to
  perform a test against the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable. The
  value of that variable would be something like
  `C:/mywebsite/value/value` or `C:/mywebsite/css/style.css`.
- `matchType="IsFile"` tells the engine to check if the above input matches an existing file on disk.
- `negate="true"` tells the engine to invert the result of the check, such that the condition is met when the input **does not** match an existing file, instead of when it does match.

Comment: Sorry if I'm sounding silly here, but am I right in thinking matchType should be replaced with the filename, in my case review.aspx?  -- After a bit of reading, it doesn't seem so, this solution didn't seem to work unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: No, matchType should not be replaced with the filename. The matchType attribute value should be "IsFile". Seems like the issue may be that I accidentally wrote it with a lowercase i, while it should be uppercase. Can you try with uppercase i and see if it works?

Comment: It seems to work. Can I ask, what is this actually doing? Checking is it's accessing review.aspx basically? Also, with any other rewrites which don't match a file -- wouldn't they conflict?

Comment: @GerryHodson I have updated my answer with a more detailed explanation of how the condition works. Hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: @GerryHodson Did it end up solving your issue or are you still unsure about how it works?

Comment: Hi @conyc. It works, kinda, and I understand the concept. The problem we're facing with this solution or any for that matter is that it'll conflict if we ever rewrite anything with two segments which isn't a physical file. Say if now we're doing /categoryname/name, and we want to add /size/brand for example, they'd conflict. Any wisdom?

Comment: @GerryHodson Do you mean that in the example with /size/brand that it would need to be rewritten to something else than /review.aspx?c={R:1}&amp;t={R:2}?

Comment: Currently, it's /review.aspx?c={R:1}&amp;t={R:2} to /value/value. Problems will arise if for example, I wanted to rewrite something else with two segments, like dummy.aspx?k={R:1}&amp;s={R:2} to /differentval/differentval. Because the rule matches two segments, nothing else. Ideally, I'd make the first-word static to differentiate but this isn't an option with the project I'm doing. :/

Comment: @GerryHodson Yeah, unfortunately it's impossible to distinguish these kind of URLs from each other and apply different rewrite rules. If you need different rules like that, the only solution I see would be to have some kind of prefix that can be used to tell them apart. e.g. /review/value/value and /dummy/differentval/differentval.

Comment: I thought so! Well, I've given you the answer because it is a good answer, it's a shame about the conflict though! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Because of the match pattern, you may need to add an exclusion, something like:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.js|\.css|\.jpg" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```